# How to navigate a tree using Apache Beam model

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a pipeline that starts receiving a list of categories IDs.

In a `ParDo` I execute a `DoFn` that calls a REST API using those IDs as parameter and returns a `PCollection` of a `Category` object.

```
.apply("Read Category", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, Category>(){});
```

In a second `ParDo` I persist this `Category` objects, read his children attribute and return his children IDs.

```
.apply("Persist Category", ParDo.of(new DoFn<Category, String>(){});
```

I would like to repeat the first `ParDo` again over the list of IDs returned by the second `ParDo` until there is no children categories.

How can I perform this with the Apache Beam model benefiting from the parallel processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Beam currently does not provide any primitives for iterative parallel processing. There are some workarounds you can employ, e.g. some of them are listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236826/iterative-processing-in-dataflow).

Another alternative is to write a simple Java function that will traverse the tree for a specific top-level ID (recursively fetching categories and children starting from a given ID), and use ParDo to apply that function in parallel - but, obviously, there will be no distributed parallelism within that function.

You could also partially "unroll" the iteration in the pipeline first, to get a bunch of distributed parallelism across the first few levels of the tree - e.g. build a pipeline with a sequence of a couple of the first and second ParDo, and then apply a third ParDo that applies the iterative Java function to traverse the remaining levels.

Note that, if you are executing on Dataflow or any other runner that supports the fusion optimization, most likely you'll need to use one of the tricks for [preventing fusion](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#preventing-fusion).

Comment: Thanks @jkff, I wiil try the partially unroll strategy.